# How to set Python 2.7 as default in Fedora 13

Tags: python, python-2.7, fedora

I have installed Python 2.7 on my system which is loaded with Fedora 13. But when I check the Python version, it is 2.6. Also, installing some packages which are dependent on 2.7 will not work.

Actually when we install Fedora 13 Python 2.6 comes as default, but after I install Python 2.7 it is not taking in Fedora 13. Anybody know how we can set the manually installed Python 2.7 to be default in Fedora 13 instead of the default Python 2.6?

Comment: I'm no expert in Fedora, but you probably could just uninstall python 2.6?

Comment: Did you try using update-alternatives? 2.7 is backwards compatible with 2.6, so that should work fine.

Comment: Yah we have installed 2.7 and also make default python as 2.7 but when i try to run the command "mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages tawlk" it showing error as cannot install in python 2.6

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is not that easy as many system tool depend on Python. Try to use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to create an isolated Python environment for your packages.